# Implementation of google places using VueJs in Hybrid mobile application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-places-api, quasar-framework

I am trying to implement searching of google places using vue js in hybrid mobile application. Searching functionality is working fine but when I click on the list of the places I can't select any of them.

I have used [vue-google-places](https://github.com/yariksav/vue-google-places) library and [vue-google-autocomplete](https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete) library. In both libraries I am facing the same issue.

```
<template>
  <q-item>
    <q-item-main>
      <q-field :error="$v.serial.$error">
        <VueGooglePlaces
          api-key="api-key"
          class="subheading"
          :enable-geolocation="true"
          types="(cities)"
          @placechanged="onPlaceChanged"
        >
          <input
            ref="address"
            float-label="Serial Number"
            type="text"
            v-model="address"
            clearable
            @blur="$v.serial.$touch"
          />
        </VueGooglePlaces>

        <vue-google-autocomplete
          id="map"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Start typing"
          v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
        ></vue-google-autocomplete>
      </q-field>
    </q-item-main>
  </q-item>
</template>

import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "vue-google-autocomplete";
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  name: "ScanBarcodePage",
  components: {
    "page-title": PageTitleComponent
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.$refs.address) {
      this.$refs.address.focus();
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      address: "",
      serial: "",
      places: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getAddressData: function(addressData, placeResultData, id) {
      this.address = addressData.formatted_address;
    },
    onPlaceChanged: function(addressData, placeResultData, id) {
      this.address = addressData.formatted_address;
    }
  }
}
```

I have added the sample code above. I am not getting any error but when I type some character in text field it shows list of places but I can't select any of them. But the same plugin is working fine for browser.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full error log you're getting and sample code you're running? If you are having issues with both libraries then chances are something is wrong with your environment or API key, but we need more info from your side to be able to help.

Comment: i have added the sample code and the explanation about what i am trying to do and what i am getting.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't been able to test your code on mobile yet, but those libraries do work on the browser. When you say you "can't select" the Autocomplete predictions, do you mean you literally cannot select any place from the dropdown list? do they disappear as soon as you hover over the list? or do you click on one but nothing happens afterwards? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Also does the list of places disappear after a split second, or do they remain until you hover over them and/or you click on a place? If you cannot click on any place, is it because the list is frozen/unresponsive or because it disappears? Once it does, can you type an address again and does the Autocomplete predictions list show up again or is it never back at all?

Comment: And also, for testing and troubleshooting purposes, try using the exact same code from the library's examples found in the documentation. Does this issue happen anyway? or do you only see this unexpected behavior when using your own custom code?

Comment: I have added the gif for your reference. And yes i can't select from dropdown list.When i type some thing in text box it shows list of places but i can't select any of them. And yes list of places remain open until we click on some other place. When we type again in text box then it shows the updated result.  I have tried the sample code but it is working only in browser.

Comment: Thanks I see. This actually looks like a plugin issue, especially if you've tried with the plugin's sample code. I've also found this issue reported back in 2018 here https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete/issues/101

Comment: Note that that library hasn't been updated for over a year. What about the other one, vue-google-places? do you have the exact same issue on mobile?

Comment: Yes the 2nd text box is vue-google-places and same issue is happening there also.

Comment: Very interesting. Both libraries work perfectly on browser. Once I get a chance to test this on mobile with apache cordova I'll get back to you.

Comment: Heya, I'm going home now and gonna set up the quasar + cordova environment to test this. In the meantime I was actually thinking that this issue may be due to having multiple instances of Place Autocomplete, bc calling the API multiple times can cause problems. Have you tried using only the vue-google-places library? As in remove the other one from your app completely and just try with one instance of Autocomplete from vue-google-places library. Do you get the same exact issue?

Comment: Another possibility may be that you aren't using a valid API key. Is billing enabled on your project? Is the Places API enabled? Is your API key restricted? Double check these in the meantime if you can. I'll get back to once I've tested this with my own API key.

Comment: Okay @divyang-solanki I have tested the vue-google-autocomplete library on Android via apache cordova; it works perfectly. List of places displayed, I can select one fine. Just like on the browser. So the issue must be with your setup or API key. Can you please double check the above?

Comment: It might as well be related to the emulator you're using. Have you tried a physical device? Let me walk you through what I did in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that these libraries are conflicting with each other due to calling the Maps API twice. Try implementing only one of them to rule this out.

Here's what I did to make [vue-google-autocomplete](https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete) work on mobile (Android) in a hybrid app via Apache cordova.

First some context here, I created a vue + cordova app via [vue-cli-plugin-cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-cordova).

In `/public/index.html`, add your Maps API script with a **valid** API key within the `<head>` element:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Then go to `/src/App.vue` and replace all content with the code from the library's documentation's [example](https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Your Address</h2>

        <vue-google-autocomplete
            ref="address"
            id="map"
            classname="form-control"
            placeholder="Please type your address"
            v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
            country="sg"
        >
        </vue-google-autocomplete>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueGoogleAutocomplete from 'vue-google-autocomplete'

    export default {
        components: { VueGoogleAutocomplete },

        data: function () {
            return {
              address: ''
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            // To demonstrate functionality of exposed component functions
            // Here we make focus on the user input
            this.$refs.address.focus();
        },

        methods: {
            /**
            * When the location found
            * @param {Object} addressData Data of the found location
            * @param {Object} placeResultData PlaceResult object
            * @param {String} id Input container ID
            */
            getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData, id) {
                this.address = addressData;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then plug in a device (or emulator) and run your app. You should be able to select a place from Autocomplete predictions without problem.

If you still can't, then check that your API key is in fact valid, i.e. it must be properly (un)restricted and belong to a Cloud project that has billing, JavaScript API & Places API enabled. More info in [Google's guide here](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started).

Really hope this helps you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198694/discussion-on-answer-by-evan-implementation-of-google-places-using-vuejs-in-hybr).